# ActionMailer and a self-signed SSL Cert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, discourse

I have an application (an installation of [Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/)) that I'm trying to deploy. However, the email server that it is pointed at has a self-signed ssl cert for SMTP.

Is there a workaround for this? Or do I need to find a way to send mail using a "valid" SSL cert?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting from your Rails app?  Are you seeing something like an OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError ?

Comment: @AlvinLee No, I'm actually get a Net::ReadTimeout for the call. The username, password etc is all correct.

Comment: @AlvinLee and changing it to not use SSL fixed it, so it's something to do with the SSL cert.

Answer (score 1):

Few things actually care that deeply about a proper cert for SMTP. Mostly user agents.

If the cert is a problem you won't get timeouts, you'll get validation errors. I suspect what's happening is that you're trying to connect over the SMTPS port which isn't listening or exposed by the firewall.

Try using SMTP+STARTTLS. That negotiates TLS over port 25 or 587 instead of trying to connect directly to 465.